# Is this picture of a statue of the Shakyamuni Buddha?

Tags: statue

I really need help identifying who the below represents... is it 
Siddhartha Gautama (Shakyamuni Buddha)?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yep.  Probably Thai judging by the pointed top knot.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure that is made in Siam, it may be Lao, Lanna (shan), Khmer or some Burmese counries. 
But, it is statue of image of imagination of autor's sight on the mind about Shakyamuni )